# The second fundamental form of geodesic sphere in space form

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

[image][image]

This is from *Geometry Analysis* by Peter Li. He said that in a space form, the inequality (2.4) will become an equality. I think it's because the second fundamental form of geodesic sphere in space form is $h_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$. But I can't prove it.

Comment: We don't have $h_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$ in space forms. This quantity depends on 1) the curvature of the space form 2) the radius of the sphere.

Comment: Since you did not provide any information on (2.1) or (2.2), we can't tell much more than: in space forms, there is equality in (2.3) since $H$ is a multiple of the identity matrix (that is, geodesic spheres are umbilical).

Comment: I have add the picture of (2.1) and (2.2).

Comment: Then it is just a matter of rewritting things: in (2.2), replace the sum $\sum_{ij}h_{ij}^2$ by $H^2/(m-1)$ and you get the first RHS of (2.4). Then, replace $H$ by $J'/J$ thanks to (2.1) to get the second RHS of (2.4).

Comment: Thanks very much. But I still have a problem that why geodesic sphere is umbilical.

Comment: These are computations that can be deduced from some particular Jacobi fields. It should have been set up before this study. For instance, a sphere of radius $r$ have second fundamental form $II(u,v) = \frac{1}{r}\langle u,v\rangle$ in the euclidean space, $II(u,v) = \mathrm{cotanh}(r) \langle u,v \rangle$ in the hyperbolic space.

Comment: Thanks very much. Could you recommend some books or papers about it.

Comment: I don't have any reference right now (shame on me). You can still ask a question about it (or find an ancient one) on this site and people (including me) will be happy to answer